# Get data from AJAX - How to

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables

I have a script, that takes the value from two select tags, and then do a simple math multipy to calculate a price. The thing I need, but cannot figure out is, how to get **that** calculated price, and use it as an php variable in a POST form.

As the calculated price is dynamic, how can I archive this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?  If so, it should be very easy to post the value to the server using the jQuery "post" function. Just pass the calculated value in the data parameter, i.e. $.post(url, {myVal : calculatedPrice});  Then you should be able to retrieve the "myVal" parameter on the server.

Comment: Guys, stop telling him to use jQuery. I think it's better to start with a self written ajax function instead of jQuery. That way he really learns more about AJAX.

Comment: @dotweb - He tagged the question with jQuery, which is why jQuery answers have been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send that value directly to a PHP script, you can use the jQuery `post` method:

```
$.post("yourScript.php", { price: yourPriceVar }, function(data) {
    //Success! Do something interesting
});
```

Alternatively, you could set the `value` of a hidden input element to your calculated value, so that it can be submitted along with the rest of your form:

```
$("#hiddenInput").val(yourPriceVar);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenInput" name="price" />
```

Comment: This is the total price calculated: 
var totalValue = exposureValue*clickValue;

It will then look like : price: totalValue ?

Comment: Yes, replace `yourPriceVar` with the name of the variable containing your calculated value.

Answer (score 1):

to set the calculated price in the form use :

```
document.FORMNAME.FIELDNAME.value = CALCULATED_VALUE;
```

or jquery style

```
$('input[name="FIELDNAME"]').value(CALCULATED_VALUE);
```

in your javascript.

in the form add an hidden field IE.

```
<input type="hidden" name="FIELDNAME" value="" />
```

Comment: Will this be a secure way of doing it? Wont it be possible to change POST data OR value or something?

Comment: @Oliver - It would always be possible to change the data sent to the server. That's one of the reasons it's so important to always validate any user input on the server side.

Comment: There's no way to avoid the possibility of the data being changed or faked on the client side, so make sure your web app treats input as such, especially if there is a database involved. Depending on what the input is this could mean escaping strings to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or checking user permissions before making changes to the database.

Comment: This is wrong. The input is named `FIELDNAME`, not `FORMNAME`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using $.ajax() or $.post(), simply append a new value to data parameter

if you are using common form submit, simply create a new input with the name attribute inside the form and set the calculated price to the value