# Validate DATA - jQuery/Ajax (PHP)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post, validation

I have a javascript that gets the value from 2 SELECT tags, and at last it takes those two values and multiply them.

The script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
  function displayVals() {
  var exposureValue = $("#mark").val();
  if(exposureValue == 1){
      exposureValue = <?php echo $sdata['ad_cost_micro']; ?>;
  }
  if(exposureValue == 2){
      exposureValue = <?php echo $sdata['ad_cost_mini']; ?>;
  }
  if(exposureValue == 3){
      exposureValue = <?php echo $sdata['ad_cost_standard']; ?>;
  }
  if(exposureValue == 4){
      exposureValue = <?php echo $sdata['ad_cost_extended']; ?>;
  }
  var clickValue = $("#series").val();
  var totalValue = exposureValue*clickValue;
  $("#price").html("<span style='font-size:22px;color:#3A8913;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;'>$" + totalValue + "</span>");

  jQuery('#p').val(exposureValue*clickValue);

  }

     $("select").change(displayVals);
        displayVals();      
        </script>
```

As you can see, the totalValue is added to a hidden INPUT with ID="p".

**My question is** how can I secure the value of id="p", so it's not possible to do a INJECTION or change the post data or something.

Thanks.

Comment: Validate it on the server side. Never rely solely on client side validation.

Comment: Also, you might want to accept more answers. The code in this question comes from an answer I gave you yesterday, which has not been accepted.

Comment: What question was that? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017636/get-data-from-ajax-how-to

Comment: So sorry about that. Answered.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I secure the value of id="p", so it's not possible to do a INJECTION or change the post data or something.

You can't. It will always be possible to change the data on client side.

You will need to protect your server-side logic against manipulations, like for example checking whether the values posted make sense.

Comment: But how can I validate it, before the form is submitted on the page?

Comment: @Oliver why do you need to validate it before submission? Using client side validation makes sense when you want to keep users from making mistakes, but you can't protect against a malicious injection on client side anyway.

Comment: Well, users they select their price (the price is received from the script above), when they have selected their price, they click "Buy Now". This will redirect them to AlertPay / PayPal. Although, they can easily change the data of the price there. Therefore, I need to validate it, before data is submitted.